# Device runtime with specified battery

Tags: batteries

How long will a 12V 30W device run on 12V 65AH battery, if the battery is first fully charged and the battery is dedicated to this one device?

Comment: Use the W to get A then A and time.

Comment: You must define all voltage thresholds...start stop. but . roughly 30W load from 780 Wh = 26h ( only when fresh battery and fully charged )

Answer (score 1):

Details are missing so an accurate calculation cannot be made.
A "12V" battery starts at about 13.8V then its voltage drops as it is used. You did not say what is the minimum voltage of the device that you are powering.
You also did not say the minimum voltage of the battery when it has provided 65Ah.

Answer (score 1):

26 hours if everything behaves ideally as you described.  12V/30W is 2.5A, so 65AH/2.5A = 26 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Ah is Amps x hours, so in theory a 65 Ah battery can produce 65 A for 1 hour, or 32.5 A for 2 hours etc. If we naively also assume that the battery produces 12 V throughout the discharge then the 12 V 30 W device would draw 30/12 = 2.5 A, and the battery would last 65/2.5 = 26 hours.

In practice a typical lead-acid battery's rated capacity is for 20 hours or longer. If discharged in 1 hour it would only achieve approximately half the rated capacity. In this case we are expecting over 20 hours so the achieved capacity should be close to the battery's rating.

However when a Lead-acid battery is fully discharged the plates are stressed and irreversible chemical reactions occur, so it wears out faster than normal. The usual recommendation for a deep cycle battery is no more than 80% discharge, and for a standard battery 50%. So depending on the battery type and how well you want to treat it, the practical run time could be 20% to 50% less than the rated capacity indicates.

Another factor which can have some effect is the voltage, which drops during discharge. At low current it might start at ~13V and go down to 11V, so although the average is ~12V the load might draw more current at the beginning and less at the end, or the other way around depending on how it operates. A heater or light bulb draws more current at higher voltage, but a switching power supply does the opposite. This may make a small difference to the run time.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit hard to accurately predict that without knowing a lot about the battery for example:
The depth of discharge allowed by battery chemistry
Battery internal resistance and its true AH rating which may not he same as claimed by different suppliers.

A good way would be to measure this could be by using simple energy meter that measure total energy input and output during a charge and discharge cycle.
An answer above gives a best case figure but in reality most battery cannot be discharged to a very low level of charge and neither are claimed AH rating  entirely reliable for all brands.